# Equivalent of Window.scrollTo() without animation?

Tags: javascript, ios, gwt, mobile-safari

On the Window class, we have:

```
Window.getScrollTop();
```

and:

```
Window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Is there a way to set the scroll **without** animation? On ios, calling Window.scrollTo() does an animation. I'd like to just set the scroll without any animation.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot test this on iOS, but maybe if you use `document.body.scrollTop = XX;` (Or whichever element you are scrolling in) there will be no animation?

Comment: I tried "Document.get().setScrollTop(0);", but I still get the animated scroll effect. This happens in firefox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could'nt you just use anchor tags .. ?
you could set the document.location to that anchor (#top)